# How can I make scanbd work on Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian, scanner

I am trying to configure a Raspberry Pi with Raspbian to be a scan server with `scanbd` and `SANE` for my Canon CanoScan LIDE 60. As the buttons are not directly supported, I had to manually compile the latest `scanbd` as described at https://riptutorial.com/raspberry-pi/example/22822/configure-sane-to-scan-from-the-network with the `--enable-scanbuttond` configuration, which worked but I failed in the connection between `scanbd` and `SANE`.

### What did I get so far?

1. The scanner works (Scans) with `scanimage` and is shown by `scanimage -L`
2. After compiling and configuring `scanbd` running `scanbd -d7 -f` shows my scanner and also button presses, I am also able to trigger scripts when `scanbd` is running in foreground to initiate scanning.

### Where am I stuck?

As soon as I remove everything except `net` from the config of `SANE` and configure `xinetd` as described, `scanimage -L` does not list any scanners anymore and therefore I cannot scan through `scanimage`. So it seems something is wrong with the communication or rights.

When I run `scanbd -d7 -f` in the output I see

```
scanbd: start dbus thread
scanbd: scbtn_poll
scanbd: Not Primary Owner (-1)
scanbd: Name Error (Connection ":1.151" is not allowed to own the service "de.kmux.scanbd.server" due to security policies in the configuration file)
```

And it seems that part of the problem is, that `scanbm` cannot listen on 6566:

```
systemctl status scanbm.socket 
● scanbm.socket - scanbd/saned incoming socket
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/scanbm.socket; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: resources)
   Listen: [::]:6566 (Stream)
 Accepted: 0; Connected: 0;

Feb 14 19:38:22 RaspberryPrinter systemd[1540]: scanbm.socket: Failed to create listening socket ([::]:6566): Address already in use
Feb 14 19:38:22 RaspberryPrinter systemd[1]: scanbm.socket: Failed to receive listening socket ([::]:6566): Input/output error
Feb 14 19:38:22 RaspberryPrinter systemd[1]: scanbm.socket: Failed to listen on sockets: Input/output error
Feb 14 19:38:22 RaspberryPrinter systemd[1]: scanbm.socket: Failed with result 'resources'.
Feb 14 19:38:22 RaspberryPrinter systemd[1]: Failed to listen on scanbd/saned incoming socket.
Feb 14 23:57:46 RaspberryPrinter systemd[16760]: scanbm.socket: Failed to create listening socket ([::]:6566): Address already in use
Feb 14 23:57:46 RaspberryPrinter systemd[1]: scanbm.socket: Failed to receive listening socket ([::]:6566): Input/output error
Feb 14 23:57:46 RaspberryPrinter systemd[1]: scanbm.socket: Failed to listen on sockets: Input/output error
Feb 14 23:57:46 RaspberryPrinter systemd[1]: scanbm.socket: Failed with result 'resources'.
Feb 14 23:57:46 RaspberryPrinter systemd[1]: Failed to listen on scanbd/saned incoming socket.
```

But `netstat -tulpn` doesn't tell me who: `tcp6       0      0 :::6566                 :::*                    LISTEN      -`

Any idea how to solve this and what the overall issue is? What files/logs do you need to see to help?

Answer (score 0):

you needs root for this:

```
user@box:~$ sudo ss -l -n -p | grep 6566 | xargs
tcp LISTEN 0 4096 *:6566 *:* users:((systemd,pid=1,fd=84))
```